# 5E rules regarding armor and being prone

Tags: armor, prone

In 5E, the rules seem pretty straightforward, but clear, regarding armor and the associated AC. However, it seems a little out of balance for characters who fall prone.

Does, or should, the AC for a character change if they are prone? For example, the Paladin in my group I am DM'ing was wearing plate armor and was knocked unconscious, falling prone. As far as I can tell, this means he still retains his 18 AC, regardless of the fact he is no longer moving.

Should the AC stay at 18 or get reduced? Am I missing where this might be covered?

Comment: Welcome! I guess you are talking about D&D? Please specify the game by adding the appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: Did you read the section in the rules of what ever RPG game you are talking about? They may give some advance for the attacker, when the target is unconscious (for example D&D 5e does).

Comment: Your title asks about a change in AC for being _prone_, but your question asks about a change in AC for being prone _and unconscious_.